# ironpython read XML with xmlns

Tags: xml, ironpython

I am a beginner and trying my best with iron python and .Net libraries for XML.
I received an XML file looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Test xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd">
  <People>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
  </People>
  <People>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>Sue</Name>
  </People>
</Test>
```

I constantly fail to read the xml.
My code for reading is:

```
def readXml():
    doc = XmlTextReader(filename)
    while doc.Read():
        if doc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element and doc.Name == "ID":
            outlist.append("Name = %s" %(doc.ReadElementString()))
.....
```

but my result is an empty list.
When I change my XML to

```
...
<Test>
...
```

I read the whole XML easily. I add objects and write to XML 
as I know that I am faking by exchanging the line in the source XML and add it after manipulation. I am curious what I am missing and why I am failing with namespaces in my sample.

Comment: Please increase your care of orthography in the future. BTW you can always edit _your own_ question. If you do not know how, please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). It may have happened that our edits did overlap, hence the problems. Sorry if that handicapped you, please try again to edit your question.